# Extract data from db then pass it to qtreeview

Tags: python, sql, pyqt

I'm totally a newbie in PyQt. I have this project in mind. I want to search data from my database and if it finds it, it will display the selected data to my QTreeView. I have already a query that can connect to my Postgresql Database. My table for example is composed of pkey,itemcode,description and Quantity. I have a QLineEdit in my Gui. In that QLineEdit,it will search the ItemCode from my table and when it finds an item, it will automatically send that item data to my QTreeView with its details. How can this be possible. I hope you could help me. Please.

Here is my Code:

**connection.py**

```
def createConnection(db):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setPort(5432)
    db.setDatabaseName("posdb")
    db.setUserName("username")
    db.setPassword("password")
    if not db.open():
        QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning(None,"Test", QtCore.QString("Database Error: %1").arg(db.lastError().text()))
        sys.exit(1)
    ok = db.open()


def sqlquery():
    query = QSqlQuery(db)
    query.prepare("Select itemcode, description, srp, vat from items Where itemcode=:itemcode;");
    if query.next():
        itemcode = query.value(0).toInt()
        description = query.value(1).toString()
        srp = query.value(2).toInt()
        vat = query.value(3).toInt()
    query.bindvalue(":itemcode", QtCore.QVariant(itemcode))
    query.exec_()
    return True
```

In my baseui.ui, i convert it to .py, then in there, it has QLineEdit,how can I use it in my main.py? Like sort of calling it as function. Thanks again JDI.

here's my main.py

```
import baseui,connection
from baseui import Ui_Dialog
from connection import createConnection

class PosForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(PosForm,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = baseui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        lineedit = QLineEdit(self.ui)
        selectitem = lineedit.toInt

def initializeModel(model):
    model = QSqlTableModel()
    model.setTable('items')
    model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
    model.select()

def view(model):
    view = QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
    initializeModel(model)
    view = PosForm()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of [examples here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/examples-sql.html) about how to use QtSql to populate views from your database queries. They are all in C++ but the examples pretty much translate across to PyQt.

In a nutshell, you would use a combination of [QSqlDatabase](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsqldatabase.html), [QSqlTableModel](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsqltablemodel.html), and [QSqlQuery](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsqlquery.html)

- **QSqlDatabase**: Creates the connection object to your database using a specific driver (in your case, Postgresql
- **QSqlTableModel**: You give this your database object and it will handle receiving the results of the queries as data. It can be connected to a table view
- **QSqlQuery**: If you want to specify a custom sql query, you can set this on your QSqlTableModel.

With these set up, you simply to myTableView.setModel(mySqlTableModel), where `myTableView` is a `QTableView`

**Update: To reflect recent code update**

I have no idea whats going on with that code, but it does a lot of strange stuff. There are top level functions that take arguments, but then go ahead and create new ones. Like when you create a QSqlTableModel in your main, then pass it to the function which goes and creates a new one. And your create database function which just creates another database. I don't really understand the logic in all the separate functions. Here is just a simplified version of your code:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql
from baseui import Ui_Dialog

class PosForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(PosForm,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = baseui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # save a reference to your line edit so you can refer to it
        self.lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.ui)

        selectitem = lineedit.toInt # what is this?

        # Your database needs to be created so you can pass it to your model
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL", "MyDatabaseConnectionName")
        db.setHostName("localhost")
        db.setPort(5432)
        db.setDatabaseName("posdb")
        db.setUserName("username")
        db.setPassword("password")
        if not db.open():
            QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning(
                self,
                "Database Connection Error", 
                "Database Error: %s" % db.lastError().text()
            )
            sys.exit(1)  # you want your whole program to exit?

        self.db = db

        # pass the database to the model
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self, self.db)
        self.model.setTable('items')
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)

        # create the view and set the model
        self.view = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)


    def setItemCode(self, itemCode):
        """ Set a new itemCode value for the sql query select """
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare("Select itemcode, description, srp, vat from items Where itemcode=:itemcode;")
        query.bindvalue(":itemcode", itemCode)
        self.model.setQuery(query)
        self.model.select()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = PosForm()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The important things to note:

- In your init, the database is created, and then passed into the QSqlTableModel.
- Your model is set on the view right there. All the UI should be set up right there in the init unless you have a compelling reason to separate out the logic.
- The only extra method I have defined here is `setItemCode`. This allows you to pass in another `itemCode` value and have the query updated on your model.
- Your `lineedit` is now `self.lineedit` so you can refer to it again in other methods.
- instance methods require a `self` parameter. You were just defining a bunch of global functions to do little bits of work on your class.

Comment: Man,thank you for your quick reply. Where can i post my code here so that you can correct it? Thank you so much JDI.

Comment: Here is my connection.py
def createConnection():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost")
    db.setPort(5432)
    db.setDatabaseName("posdb")
    db.setUserName("nethanjavier")
    db.setPassword("guess")
    if not db.open():
        QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning(None,"Test", QtCore.QString("Database Error: %1").arg(db.lastError().text()))
        sys.exit(1)
    ok = db.open()

Comment: continuation on my connection.py
def sqlquery():
    query = QSqlQuery(db)
    query.prepare("Select itemcode, description, srp, vat from items Where itemcode=:itemcode;");
    if query.next():
        itemcode = query.value(0).toInt()
        description = query.value(1).toString()
        srp = query.value(2).toInt()
        vat = query.value(3).toInt()
    query.bindvalue(":itemcode", QtCore.QVariant(itemcode))
    query.exec_()
    return True

Comment: @Nethan: What specifically is the issue with your current code? It has a ton of strangeness so I don't know where to start.

Comment: Hi JDI, in my connection.py where i define createConnection, that's a correct code right? But in my sqlquery,I think it's bad. Right? What I want in that query is to make an SQL query by extracting the data from my database and assigning it to each column, like itemcode,description,srp and vat. What's the right way of doing it JDI?

Comment: @Nethan: My last update actually addresses this. I think you were separating the logic a little wrong. Your `createConnection` was opening a connection (twice actually), but you were never setting up your model to use it. I reorganized all that into the init of your widget for simplicity and connected everything up. Then I added a single method that would recreate the query for you and set it on the model

Comment: Hi JDI, in your update you use `self.lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.ui)` how can I use this QLineEdit to my `query.bindvalue(":itemcode", itemCode)`? Like I will input a number there and then that binding to `itemCode` will fine in the database.

Comment: The missing piece is to just connect a signal from the QLineEdit to the setItemCode method I showed you. Maybe using the textEdited signal: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#textEdited